# video with .avi format not supporting in html5,showing error?

Tags: html, video

Hi i'm using html5 video format type .avi,but it is not working showing error as No video with supported format and MIME type found.Could anybody tell me weather html5 supports all formats or not?

Answer (score 0):

reference: http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html#what-works

Notice that none of the major browsers support .avi containers. Also be aware that the container is not the only thing that matters - the codecs inside the container matter as well!

Answer (score 0):

It does not officially support features of more recent container formats like embedded metadata. It does not even officially support most of the modern video and audio codecs in use today.